# Получение обычного адреса по его части

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли получения адреса по его части через api Yandex maps?

Я ввожу "Красная площадь 1", а в отчет получаю "Красная площадь, 1 Москва, Россия, 125009"

Спасибо

Comment: юзайте google geocode или яндекс

Answer (score 1):

Ссори за поспешность, нашел сам ответ )
[https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=KEY&format=json&geocode=Тверская+6+москва](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=KEY&format=json&geocode=%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F+6+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0)

Вдруг кому пригодится.